# Task Manager shows high kernel time

Tags: windows-server-2012, kernel, cpu-usage, performance-monitoring, performance-tuning

Foreward:
Hardware: dual-socket Intel Xeon, 128gb memory, hardware RAID-1 SSD
OS:  Windows 2012 R2 Standard w/ Remote Desktop Services

The Task Manager for one of our terminal/application servers shows the majority of the CPU-time as kernel-time.  For example, if I am seeing 75% CPU-time, kernel-time will likely be around the 50% mark, meaning that 2/3 of CPU usage is in the kernel.

I'd like to find out why.

Under this example, when viewing the Details tab of Task Manager, were I to add up the processes, I'd get to 25%, while System Idle would be sitting at 75%.  The System process will be very low (generally just 1-2%).

If I check the Resource Monitor, and add up its top processes, I get the same results.  Again, the System process will be very low.

If I check Process Explorer, and add up its top process, I get the same results.  Again, the System process will be very low.

I've installed the Windows Performance Toolkit from the Windows 10 SDK.  Unfortunately, the Windows Performance Recorder fails to run on this server.  I've never tried to use it on a Windows 2012 R2 Remote Desktop Server before.  Perhaps that's the issue.  Otherwise, I have no clue what its problem is.  It does not present any crash messages, and there are no entries for it failing to run in the Application log.  It simply self-terminates within a second or two of being launched.

So, now I'm at an impasse... Where should I turn to next to learn why I'm seeing such high kernel-time?

Thanks

Update:  We are not memory- or disk-bound.  I/O is not a problem, here.

Comment: Do you have and IIS instance running there ? http.sys runs in Kernel space.

Comment: IIS is required for RDS.  Otherwise, IIS is unused.  So, yes, it is installed... but unused.

Comment: How many connections does RDS handle? RDS is another iteration of Terminal Services and that one just expanded kernel space. Have a look here for an brief explanation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383509(v=vs.85).aspx .